# How do I implement a construct function on public function?

Tags: php

Hi I have a problem where I just can't figure out how to implement a construct function on this php that I have here:

```
class zendesk{

private $client;

function __construct() {

public function sync_organisations() {
    $loader = require LIBPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader->setPsr4("GuzzleHttp\\", APPPATH . '../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/');

    $subdomain = "Name";
    $username  = "name@name.name"; // replace this with your registered email
    $token     = "token"; // replace this with your token

    $client = new ZendeskAPI($subdomain);
    $client->setAuth('basic', ['username' => $username, 'token' => $token]);}
```

Could somebody show me how to implement a public function __construct() {?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. The simple answer would be `public function __construct(){}` but I doubt this is (all) you are asking for. Maybe add how you want to use this class `zendesk`!?

Comment: @Jeff  thank you for your comment. I will change the question!

Comment: An empty constructor does nothing so it does beg the question - which @Jeff also asks - why do you need a constructor, what work do you want to do inside it? Normally a constructor exists so you can pass values in or do initialisation work when you create your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

To create a Constructor in PHP use:

```
public function __construct() {
  //Code
}
```

So for example if you want to call your function `sync_organisations()` in the constructor, you could do following:

```
class zendesk{

    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->sync_organisations();
    }

    public function sync_organisations() {
        $loader = require LIBPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: A small point - `sync_organisations();` should be `$this->sync_organisations();`